# Find the angle between asymptotes

Tags: asymptotics, problem-solving

> Sketch the locus of the centres of circles which touch two fixed and unequal circles.
>   Find the angle between the asymptotes

How shall I find the locus when the size of the circles are not fixed? What about the angle between asymptotes? Could someone help me please?

Comment: https://tube.geogebra.org/m/27216